# How to overload built-in Solr permissions

Tags: security, solr

I tried to combine a predefined permission with a custom permission in Solr's `security.json`. That does not seem to work with Solr 7.1.0.

security.json:

```json
{
"authentication":{
   "blockUnknown": true,
   "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
   "credentials":{"user1":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c=",
       "user2":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="}
},
"authorization":{
   "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
   "user-role":{"user1":"admin","user2":"user"}
   "permissions":[{"name":"shard-management","role":"*","path":"/admin/collections","params":{"action":["CREATESHARD", "DELETESHARD"]}},
     {"name":"collection-admin-edit","role":"admin"}],
}}
```

This configuration tries to assign `collection-admin-edit` permission to user1 and give access to `CREATESHARD` and `DELETESHARD` to user2. (Password is "SolrRocks" for both users, btw)

Effectively, user2 cannot call `DELETESHARD`:

```
o.a.s.s.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin This resource is configured to have a permission {
  "name":"collection-admin-edit",
  "role":"admin"}, The principal [principal: user2] does not have the right role 
o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall USER_REQUIRED auth header Basic dXNlcjI6U29sclJvY2tz context : userPrincipal: [[principal: user2]] type: [ADMIN], collections: [TeamSlide, TeamSlide,], Path: [/admin/collections] path : /admin/collections params :indent=true&action=DELETESHARD&shard=TestShard&collection=TestColl&wt=json
```

Same result when changing the order of permissions. Any way to solve this?

Comment: Not sure if you can define an authorization permission inline like that and not go through the Authorization API to define the permission?

Comment: Interesting idea. I never thought about this potential restriction. However, the settings are read without problems and returned by `curl --user user1:SolrRocks http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/authorization`. Therefore I think RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin accepts these.